# laravel not getting file on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

here I'm trying to get signature file from the user and saving into the database but I'm facing problem when I'm submitting form. I'm trying to get image file and showing it on the screen when file is being  selected . It is showing image on the screen when we select the image. when I'm submitting form the request gets null file. I'm not able to find what is or are the problems so I'm attaching my codes below.

**html code**

```
<div style="width: 90%; height: 100px; border: 2px dashed black; background: #c6c6c6;  border-radius: 5px;"><img src="#" style="width: 90%; height: 100px;" id="signatureImage"></div>
<input class="btn btn-outline-primary border-0 waves-effect waves-light" type="button" id="get_sign" value="Upload">
<input type="file" name="signature" onchange="readSignURL(this);" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" id="signatureFile">
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById('get_sign').onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById('signatureFile').click();
        };
        
        function readSignURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    
                    $('#signatureImage')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .css('display','block')
                        .width(300)
                        .height(100);
                    
                };

               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```
dd($request->file('signature'));
```

**Outputs**

[image: on screen image shown]
[image: the form submission output]

Comment: Are you sending the file with AJAX or with a standard form ? Include the code where you send the file to the server, please.

Comment: standard form without ajax because it worked in my another form . using local server

Comment: are you using multipart/form-data in your form element enctype ?

Comment: yes i am using it

Comment: you can check your HTTP request at the network tab on your devtools, if the file is not in the request the problem may be in your form. otherwise it could be that your request object is not the right one. you could use the request() helper instead